# How would you write code for unsigned addition likely to be optimized into one SSE instruction?

Tags: c++, c, sse

In C or C++ how would you write code for unsigned addition of two arrays likely to be optimized, by say GCC, into one 128bit SSE unsigned addition instruction?

Comment: What size are the array elements ? 8 bit, 16 bit, 32 bit, 64 bit ?

Comment: Just add the appropriate flags to gcc so it knows that it can use SSE optimizations. This basically means adding the flags to indicate the destination hardware that the application will run on.

Comment: +1 for asking how to write clean code and let the optimizer do its thing, rather than using ISA-specific asm/intrinsic hacks.

Answer (score 3):

```
// N number of ints to be added
// a, b input array
// c sum array
// nReg number of required vector registers

const unsigned nReg = N*sizeof(uint32_t)/sizeof(__v4si);
__v4si a[nReg], b[nReg], c[nReg];
for (unsigned i=0; i<nReg; ++i)
    c[i] = _mm_add_epi32(a[i], b[i]);

// in c++ simply
for (unsigned i=0; i<nReg; ++i)
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
```

Unroll loop and prefetch elements at your desire. Profiling is recommended. Substitute __v4si with __v16qi, __v8hi, __v2di for 8, 16, 64 bit ints.

Comment: Probably because OP asked how to write C++ or C code that will be optimized by the compiler to use SSE, not how to write some ugly machine-specific intrinsics.

Comment: The c++ example does not use intrinsics

Comment: The division by `sizeof(uint32_t)` (which is a really ugly way of writing 4...) probably does not belong in the C++ version...

Comment: Actually it was 4 in an earlier version, I edited it to make clear where it came from. But the point is, wether your compiler will vectorzie a loop, depends on the exact version, the flags (-ftree-vectorize) and the current mood of your processor :-) You can use -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=2 to get some assist as I wrote in an other answer, but the only way to make sure your compiler really uses SSE is to use intrinsics or in the case of c++ the vector types, which are for most logical and arithmetic operators are mapped to the equivalent intrinsics

Comment: Why would `N` be a number of bytes rather than a number of elements?

Comment: I allocated to many array elements. Fixed it, I hope the code comes closer to your aestetic standards :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++) c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but one question: Did you actually ever have written some code which needed to be executed in SSE?

Comment: Yes, and I wrote it in asm. However, OP's question is not about how to write SSE code but rather how to write C or C++ code that the compiler's optimizer can easily vectorize. And the best way to do that is to keep the code as simple as possible.

Comment: There is a way in between: Use the intrinsics (which are directly mapped to the asm instructions), and let the compiler do the instrcution scheduling. Especially in code which contains non-vector code and vector code mixed this may give superior results. Large blocks of SSE are better done in asm, I agree.

Comment: I generally consider the intrinsics worse. They're not just ISA-specific but also compiler-specific. But you're right about the potential advantages.

Comment: @R.: The intrinsics aren't compiler-specific.  They're specified by Intel, implemented in their C compiler `icc`, and implemented identically by `gcc`, `clang`, MSVC, ... - personally, I feel that this makes them superiour to inline asm.

Comment: I'll give you that there are arguments for both.